# Why Richardson's method is said to be sub-optimal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The Richardson's method is a simple method for solving linear system. This is a link to a tutorial, and part of it says

> [image]
>   [image]

Anyone can help explain what does this "sub-optimal" mean? Does it mean the iteration has some numerical computation problem in practice? If so, can anyone help given some reason? What is the biggest problem of this method? Thanks!

---

PS: The later part of the tutorial shows the method converges under condition that $\|I-\alpha A\|_2<1$.

Comment: This is such a simple method that it would be surprising if other better methods are not available. (For example, GMRES tends to converge much faster than this method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will risk a guess as to what the author of your tutorial meant.

Richardson's method using matrix vector multiplication, scalar multiplication and vector addition to construct a sequence of approximations to the solution of $Ax=b$. In particular,
$$ x_t \in  K_t(A,b)$$
where the Krylov space $K_t(A,b)$ is given by 
$$ K_t(A,b) = \text{span} \{b, Ab, A^2b, \dotsc, A^{t-1} b \}.$$
There are other approximations in $K_t$ which are of interest and some are better than Richardson's. In particular, the approximation delivered by the generalized minimal residual method (GMRES) is optimal in the sense that it minimizes the residual 2-norm over $K_t(A,b)$, i.e. $$x_{\text{GMRES}} \in K_t(A,b)$$ is such that
$$ \| b - Ax_{\text{GMRES}} \|_2 = \underset{z \in K_t(A,b)}{\min} \|b - Az\|_2.$$